# How to render a block with sonata block Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-admin, twig-extension

I created a block and i added some content inside of the block.I want to render the content of my block inside of the page myblock.html.twig

This is the page : myblock.html.twig

```
    {% extends sonata_block.templates.block_base %}

{% block block %}
    {{ sonata_block_render({'type':'sonata.block.service.myblock'}) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I have the following error when i refresh the page:

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

My server are still on and i can access to others pages of the website.

```
MyBlockService.php

    <?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Block;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
class MyBlockService extends BaseBlockService
{
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */


    public function execute(BlockContextInterface $block, Response $response = null)
    {
        // merge settings
        $settings = array_merge($this->getDefaultSettings(), $block->getSettings());
        return $this->renderResponse('FLYBookingsBundle:Default:myblock.html.twig', array(
            'block'     => $block,
            'settings'  => $settings
        ), $response);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block)
    {
        // TODO: Implement validateBlock() method.
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
    {
        $formMapper->add('settings', 'sonata_type_immutable_array', array(
            'keys' => array(
                array('content', 'textarea', array()),
            )
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Text (core)';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDefaultSettings()
    {
        return array();
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureSettings(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'content'    => 'Insert your custom content here',
        ));
    }


    public function __construct($name, $templating, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $templating);
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }}
```

service.yml

```
sonata.block.service.myblock:
          class: FLY\BookingsBundle\Block\MyBlockService
          arguments: [ "sonata.block.service.myblock", @templating, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
          tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }
```

Comment: You need to pass the `id` that you used when registering the block, not a number. In your case, that would be `sonata.block.service.myblock`

Comment: @Artamiel  I tried with your code, but now  i have another error: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDefaultSettings" of class "FLY\BookingsBundle\Block\MyBlockService".
Did you mean to call "setDefaultSettings"?  . The problem come from this line:  `$settings = array_merge($this->getDefaultSettings(), $blockContext->getBlock()->getSettings());`

Comment: And where does that method comes from, since it's clearly not inherited from `BaseBlockService`?

Comment: @Artamiel  Sorry for the delayed response. I updated my post with the different change you told me to do. You can check the change i made on top.  You are right  `getDefaultSettings()` have to  inherited from `BaseBlockService`. But now i have another error : `This webpage is not available`, i don't understand this error because my server is on ?

Comment: Put a search for `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` and you should find a few answers here, on SO explaining what could be possibly be triggering this error.

Comment: @Artamiel Now i know  why i was getting the error `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` is because this line was missing in my controller --> `'template' => 'SonataBlockBundle:Block:block_core_text.html.twig',` . Thank you for your help. :)